# Integral trick explanation or link

Tags: integration

We used the following integral trick in our lecture, I really can't understand why it works. I would appreciate an explanation or even just a name so i can search for it :)

So apparently:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\boldsymbol{x}\cdot f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\boldsymbol{(x-x_{a})}f(x)dx+\boldsymbol{x}_{\boldsymbol{a}}\cdot\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$$

Where $f(x)$ is some function of $x$ and $x_a$ is .. not sure about that either, probably any constant..

Comment: This is just linearity of the integral.

Comment: Is your choice of what to make bold and where to place $\cdot$ meant to imply certain quantities are vectors and hence so is $dx$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just because
$$xf(x)=(x-x_a)f(x)+x_af(x)$$
$x_a$ is a constant, so you can pull it outside of the integral.

Comment: Thabkyou ! I had a feeling it would be something stupidly simple! Thanks!